# I need a high quality image on my imageview, but I don't get any view in my imageview

Tags: java, android

This is my code for camera(i am using File Provider)
**This is MainActivity[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYPU.png)** [MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOoIV.png)

**This is my display Activity[DisplayActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0AEw.png)**

Plz help i tried so may codes and make projects again and again.

I am trying to get high quality image from the camera and display it on the imageview.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, post the code as code-formatted text in the question itself. Also, please write a title that actually paraphrases your question. Don't use it as if it's the first paragraph of your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here was an demo that can help with your project...

On Button Click...

```java
//photoFile is global variable File photoFile = null;
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try {
   photoFile = createImageFile();
   if (photoFile != null) {
       Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);
       takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
       startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 501);
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Put this method in your class

```java
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
      long timeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
      String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
      File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
      File image = File.createTempFile(
              imageFileName,  /* prefix */
              ".jpg",   /* suffix */
              storageDir      /* directory */
      );
      return image;
  }
```

Get Result from camera

```java
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          switch (requestCode) {
              case 501:
                  if (photoFile != null) {
                      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                      
                      if (bitmap != null) {
                          // you got bitmap here
                      }
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

Comment: it's giving error on bitmap

Comment: what is the error can you describe?

Comment: Its giving error on bitmap. That it is not initialized. Ask me to make a variable. I try it to make a Bitmap variable but that doesn't work to. And also the bitmap is not showing in imageview to.

Comment: but. its already works for me, even in Android S